# How can I use the window object in jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to use the `window` object in a Jasmine test.

In the test file `loader_spec.s` I have:

```
use strict;
var setupModuleLoader = require(../src/loader);

describe("setupModuleLoader", function() {
    it(exposes angular on the window, function() { 

      setupModuleLoader(window); 
      expect(window.angular).toBeDefined();

    }); 
});
```

And in the `loader.js` file I have:

```
use strict;

function setupModuleLoader(window) {
  var angular = window.angular = {}; //creates empty angular object in browser's `window`
}

module.exports = setupModuleLoader;
```

I get a reference error that `window` is not defined when I run the test.

I am working on this test using this [boilerplate](https://github.com/DavidKlassen/es6-browser-boilerplate) which uses PhantomJS.

Comment: When using Jasmin `angular` will already be available as a global variable. check the use of [inject](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject) for loading modules

Comment: Is there not a way to use the browser window object? To give some context i am following a book which builds angularjs from ground up so i am not actually using the angularjs library.

Comment: Should the first argument of the `it` function be a string. or is this a typo?

Comment: are you running jasmine test from browser or console?

Comment: i'm running it in the console. no typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have access to the `window` object, you should make sure that your tests run in browser, not node.js.

```
$ gulp test:unit
```

task in the mentioned [boilerplate](https://github.com/DavidKlassen/es6-browser-boilerplate) runs plain [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) tests and does not launch the browser. To have access to `window` and other browser-specific objects, you should place your tests in `/tests/integration` directory and run them like this:

```
$ gulp test:integration
```

It is a good practice to have your code units loosely coupled with the execution context, this is why unit tests in the boilerplate do not launch the browser. They do not expect code units to know anything about `window` or other browser objects.

One more way to solve the issue when your code depends on some external stuff is to create mocks for your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Well **window** object represent the browser window.If you running the jasmine unit test from browser then it is available in your script otherwise its not avilable.

Running from console means you are running javascript from script host.So host is not able to find the **Window** object.

The browser option does not include the aliases of the global object, window and self.

e.g.  browsers: ['Chrome']